# definition of $ \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(k) e^{-ikn} dk$ with $n$ not an integer

Tags: fourier-analysis

I know that when $f(x)$ is a $2 \pi$ periodic function, integrable on the circle $\mathbb{T}$, then for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(k) e^{-ikn} dk= \hat{f}(n).$

Now, suppose that we have the same integral, but with $n= q+r/m$, with $r/m <1$ and $q \in \mathbb{N}$. i.e. $n$ is not an integer.
Then, how can we define

$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(k) e^{-ikn} dk=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(k) e^{-ik(q+r/m)} dk ?$

Is it simply equal to zero?

Comment: Then you get the [*Fourier Transform*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Definition).

Comment: @PaulSinclair But I thought Fourier transform where from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. my integral is only on the circle

Comment: I suppose I should have looked closer at what you are doing. You say you are integrating $k$ over "the circle" $\Bbb T$, but then $k$ appears in the exponent of $e$, which is ill-defined if $k$ is not real. What exactly do you mean by "the circle" here?

Comment: well, we know $\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(k) e^{-i kn} dk = \hat{f}(n)$ for n $\in \mathbb{Z}$. my question is what happens if $n=q+r/m$ for $q \in \mathbb{N}$ and $r/m <1$. @PaulSinclair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define $g(k)=f(k)e^{-ikr/m}$.  Your integral is then $\hat g(q)$

Comment: I have seen $g(x)$ and $g'(x)$ but I have not seen $\hat g(x)$. Could you please explain to me what that is? .... I did a little bit of research and it is the *fourier transform* of a function $g$. Nevermind... I am not ready for that yet haha

Comment: It is the same transform on $g$ as $\hat f$ is on $f$.  My point is you just incorporate the $e^{-ikr/m}$ into $g$, then transform it the same way you did $f$.